# Plotting dates versus numbers in ZedGraph and C#

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have a table that has date and datasize. When I export the list its data appears as

```
11/1/10|1  
11/2/10|2  
11/3/10|16
```

I simply want to create a line graph from this data, but when I see if it's plotted or not the graph is never plotted, also is there a way to change the x axis from a 0-100 numbering to the dates that are listed?

```
private void CreateGraph_DataSource(ZedGraphControl zedGraphControl1)
{
    string project = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string sql = "select date,datasize from dbo.x where project = '"+project+"' order by date";
    DataTable projects = null;
    SqlDataAdapter dataadapt = null;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source= W ;Initial Catalog= ding;Integrated Security= SSPI");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    projects = new DataTable();
    dataadapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dataadapt.Fill(projects);
    con.Close();
    GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
    myPane.Title.Text = project;
    myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Size";
    myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Date";
    DataSourcePointList dsp = new DataSourcePointList();
    dsp.DataSource = projects;
    dsp.XDataMember = "Date";
    dsp.YDataMember = "DataSize";
    LineItem myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("DataSize", dsp, Color.DarkViolet);
    myCurve.Line.Fill = new Fill(Color.Red, Color.White);
    LineItem myCurve2 = myPane.AddCurve("Date", dsp, Color.DarkViolet);
    myCurve2.Line.Fill = new Fill(Color.Green, Color.White);
    myCurve.Line.Width = 2.0F;
    myCurve2.Line.Width = 2.0F;
    zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
    myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
}
```

Edit:

Sorry, it does appear to be graphing but the scaling is really bad, is there a way to set the scaling to start?

Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell ZedGraph that the axis is a date type:

```
myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
```

While it doesn't use a DataSource there is a [tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20081014195156/http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Tutorial%3aDate_Axis_Chart_Demo) on using the Date Axis Type.

Comment: I also needed zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();

Comment: Would you happen to know why i have to click in the zedgraphcontrol to update it with the new graph?

Comment: Call `zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();` after you update the graph to ensure it's redrawn.

Comment: I have another question if you could take a look at it, thanks.